# Angular 6 + Chart.js - Display a targeted chart from a different component on condition

Tags: angular, chart.js, angular6, angular-components

(if you wish to skip directly to the question, please scroll to the last paragraph).

I have `ChartsComponent` which is a child of `HomeComponent`.

In `charts.component.ts`, I'm using Chart.js to create several charts.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core',
import { Chart } from 'chart.js'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-charts',
  templateUrl: './charts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./charts.component.scss']
})

export class ChartsComponent implements OnInit {
  pieChart: any;
  doughnut: any;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    //Pie chart
    this.pieChart = new Chart('pieChartCanvas', {
      type: 'pie',
      ...
    });

    //Doughnut chart
    this.Doughnut = new Chart('doughnutChartCanvas', {
      type: 'Doughnut ',
      ...
    });
  }
}
```

I can call upon those two charts easily in `charts.component.html` using `<canvas id="pieChartCanvas"><canvas>` and `<canvas id="doughnutChartCanvas"><canvas>`, then add `<app-charts></app-charts>` into `home.component.html` and they will display fine. However, what I'm trying to achieve is a bit different.

> Following part has been edited.

A backend will send some data with a property value of "pie" or "doughnut" for exemple (that I would simulate with data.ts or json file). I would like to be able to set a condition (maybe via `*ngIf="pieChartCanvas"`) that would decide which of the two charts to call upon from `charts.component.ts`and be able to display it in `charts.component.html`.

Then `home.component.html` will just be here to display the component via `<app-charts></app-charts>`

Any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: I think you have some design smell somewhere. First, you must define the role of each component: you mention siblings components, but if you use one into another one, it's more a child relationship (but that's just semantic). Then a component is supposed to handle the properties it manages. If your charts are set up in your app-charts component, why the display of those charts should be managed in another top component? That feels quite weird!

Comment: @sjahan 
Yes I agree with you. The ChartsComponent should be a child of the HomeComponent. I will fix that. Ok so I need to give logic to the ChartsComponent (I will edit my question accordingly). With that in mind, which Angular element would be best to use in order to define which type of charts is being used in charts.component.html then? Basicaly, there will be a backend that will send a property ("pie" for example) if the admin wants to use a pie chart. The ChartsComponent will have to be able to select pie chart from its charts.component.ts

Comment: Pass type via input parameter into chart component from home component. Aka get type in home.component.ts then pass it into chart via type property. Does that make sense?

Comment: @AmelSalibasic I'm not sure I understand what you mean. You mean to add an `@input()` of the type (pieChart, for exemple) in `ChartsComponent` and then recover that type in the `home.component.ts` ? Maybe I'm the one not clear. Please let me know.

Comment: You should pass type of chart into chart component. There should be input inside of chart.ts like @Input() type: string, which then you should assign when you are initializing chart. You should pass this type then from home.component.ts(get type here via api) and pass to <chart [type]="typeFromHomeTs"></chart>

Comment: @TheHiddenSoul is your issue resolved or still facing similar error, i think you will have to use `@ViewChild('pieChartCanvas')` decorator